# How to remake function that group list to simple recursion?

Tags: scala, function, functional-programming

I write function that group list elements by index, with odd index in first list, even in second. But I don not know how to make it with simple recursion and don not get type mismatch.

Here is the code:

```
// Simple recursion
def group1(list: List[Int]): (List[Int], List[Int]) = list match {
  case Nil => (Nil, Nil)
  case head :: Nil => (List(head), Nil)
  case head :: tail => // how can I make this case?
}

group1(List(2, 6, 7, 9, 0, 4, 1))

// Tail recursion
def group2(list: List[Int]): (List[Int], List[Int]) = {
  def group2Helper(list: List[Int], listA: List[Int], listB: List[Int]): (List[Int], List[Int]) = list match {
    case Nil => (listA.reverse, listB.reverse)
    case head :: Nil => ((head :: listA).reverse, listB.reverse)
    case head :: headNext :: tail => group2Helper(tail, head :: listA, headNext :: listB)
  }
  group2Helper(list, Nil, Nil)
}

group2(List(2, 6, 7, 9, 0, 4, 1))
```

Comment: What did you try that caused a type mismatch?

Comment: Don't forget to add `headNext` (as in `head :: next :: tail`) to the simple recursion as well

Comment: @Bergi if I trying to do this function like another with simple recursion like this:

case head :: headnext :: tail => (head :: group1(List(tail.head)), headnext :: group1(tail.tail))

It gives me mismatch because I can not add head element to (_, _),  sorry I don not know how it calls on English.

This function is not correct, here it is going about idea

Comment: You don't want to `group1` the `.head` and `.tail` of `tail` - you just want to `group1(tail)`. And then `group1(tail)` will return a tuple of two lists. You will want to prepend `head` to the first and `headNext` to the second one. Use temporary variables so that you need to call `group1(tail)` only once and so that you can break up the result into the two lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to invoke the next recursion, unpack the result tuple, pre-pend each head element to the proper `List`, and repackage the new result tuple.

```
def group1(list: List[Int]) :(List[Int], List[Int]) = list match {
  case Nil                => (Nil, Nil)
  case head :: Nil        => (List(head), Nil)
  case hdA :: hdB :: tail => val (lstA, lstB) = group1(tail)
                             (hdA :: lstA, hdB :: lstB)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I understand how to use variable in case. But I don not know is it still functional way programming? Or this variable does not like a statement or imperative style?

Comment: This `group1()` method creates 7 variables. They are (in order) `list`, `head`, `hdA`, `hdB`, `tail`, `lstA`, and `lstB`. Every one of them is a `val` (i.e. immutable) so it doesn't conflict with the tenets of Functional Programming.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining